# BeautifoulSoup4 extract title from source code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking for a way to extract the string **Title Name** from the following source code:

```
<div class="specs__party-group">
    <a href="Url" title="Title Name" class="specs__party"  data-no-translate="true">General
    </a>
</div>
```

The package used is BeautifoulSoup4. In the source code, there are multiple

```
<a title = ... </a>
```

structures. For example:

```
<div class="show-more__fade  js_show-more-button">
    <a href="#" title="showmore">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I only want the title string from the `class="specs__party-group"` block.

Following codes (found here) did not give me the desired result:

```
title = soup.find_all('a', title=True, class_='specs__party-group')
```

Or

```
for link in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'specs__party-group'}): 
    title= link.get('title')
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Answer (score 2):

The a tag your targeting carries the class "specs__party", not "specs__party-group".

This should work:

```
title = soup.find_all('a', class_='specs__party')
```